# how to extract particular contents from a json map

Tags: json, list, flutter, api, flutter-dependencies

Here is the response from api

```
{
"title": "सरकारबाट अनुदानमा प्राप्त एम्बुलेन्समा गाँजा तस्करी",
"description": "<p>प्रहरीले हेटौंडा उपमहानगरपालिकाबाट&nbsp; ३० किलो ६०० ग्राम गाँजासहित सरकारी एम्बुलेन्सलाई नियन्त्रणमा लिएको छ ।</p><p>मकवानपुरको नेवारपानीस्थित इलाका प्रहरी कार्यालयबाट खटिएको प्रहरी टोलीले रौतहटको डुमरिया स्वास्थ्य चौकीको बा २ झ १७४९ नम्बरको एम्बुलेन्समा गाँजा तस्करी गर्ने ३ जनालाई पक्राउ गरेको हो</p><p>पक्राउचालक डुमरिया नगरपालिका–९ का मोहम्मद खलिद, डुमरिया–४ का अशोक कुमार र भारत बिहार मोतिहारीका विनोद सहनी छन् । उनीहरूले मकवानपुरकै कुनै ठाउँबाट एम्बुलेन्समा गाँजा ओसार्ने गरेको पत्ता लागेको छ ।</p><p><br></p><p>एम्बुलेन्स रोकेर हेर्दा तीन वटा झोलाभित्र ६ पोकामा राखेको गाँजा फेला परेको थियो । एम्बुलेन्सबाट ९१ हजार रूपैयाँ पनि बरामद भएको छ । एम्बुलेन्ससहित नियन्त्रणमा लिइएकाहरूमाथि अनुसन्धान भइरहेको प्रहरीले जनाएको छ ।<br></p><p>लागुऔषध नियन्त्रण ऐन, २०३३ बमोजिम दुईदेखि १० वर्षसम्म कैद र १५ हजारदेखि एक लाख रुपैयाँसम्म जरिवाना तथा सवारी साधन समेत जफत हुने व्यवस्था छ । सोही ऐनअनुसार उनीहरूमाथि कारबाही हुने प्रहरीले जनायो ।<br></p>",
"views": 372,
"author": null,
"created_at": "2020-01-26T09:15:53.000000Z",
"slug": "2020-01-26-114",
"image": "https://actpronepal.com/storage/photos/1/2020-01-265e2d58c925264.jpg",
"categories": [
{
"id": 2,
"name": "समाचार",
"parent_id": 0,
"slug": "news"
},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "अटो",
"parent_id": 0,
"slug": "employment"
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "शिक्षा",
"parent_id": 0,
"slug": "artical-interview"
}
]
}
```

i am trying to extract all categories["name"] from above response as a list of string. Help will be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution

```
void main() {
  Map tags = {
    "title": "सरकारबाट अनुदानमा प्राप्त एम्बुलेन्समा गाँजा तस्करी",
    "description":
        "<p>प्रहरीले हेटौंडा उपमहानगरपालिकाबाट&nbsp; ३० किलो ६०० ग्राम गाँजासहित सरकारी एम्बुलेन्सलाई नियन्त्रणमा लिएको छ ।</p><p>मकवानपुरको नेवारपानीस्थित इलाका प्रहरी कार्यालयबाट खटिएको प्रहरी टोलीले रौतहटको डुमरिया स्वास्थ्य चौकीको बा २ झ १७४९ नम्बरको एम्बुलेन्समा गाँजा तस्करी गर्ने ३ जनालाई पक्राउ गरेको हो</p><p>पक्राउचालक डुमरिया नगरपालिका–९ का मोहम्मद खलिद, डुमरिया–४ का अशोक कुमार र भारत बिहार मोतिहारीका विनोद सहनी छन् । उनीहरूले मकवानपुरकै कुनै ठाउँबाट एम्बुलेन्समा गाँजा ओसार्ने गरेको पत्ता लागेको छ ।</p><p><br></p><p>एम्बुलेन्स रोकेर हेर्दा तीन वटा झोलाभित्र ६ पोकामा राखेको गाँजा फेला परेको थियो । एम्बुलेन्सबाट ९१ हजार रूपैयाँ पनि बरामद भएको छ । एम्बुलेन्ससहित नियन्त्रणमा लिइएकाहरूमाथि अनुसन्धान भइरहेको प्रहरीले जनाएको छ ।<br></p><p>लागुऔषध नियन्त्रण ऐन, २०३३ बमोजिम दुईदेखि १० वर्षसम्म कैद र १५ हजारदेखि एक लाख रुपैयाँसम्म जरिवाना तथा सवारी साधन समेत जफत हुने व्यवस्था छ । सोही ऐनअनुसार उनीहरूमाथि कारबाही हुने प्रहरीले जनायो ।<br></p>",
    "views": 372,
    "author": null,
    "created_at": "2020-01-26T09:15:53.000000Z",
    "slug": "2020-01-26-114",
    "image":
        "https://actpronepal.com/storage/photos/1/2020-01-265e2d58c925264.jpg",
    "categories": [
      {"id": 2, "name": "समाचार", "parent_id": 0, "slug": "news"},
      {"id": 1, "name": "अटो", "parent_id": 0, "slug": "employment"},
      {"id": 6, "name": "शिक्षा", "parent_id": 0, "slug": "artical-interview"}
    ]
  };

List categoryNameList = [];
tags["categories"].forEach((val) => categoryNameList.add(val["name"]));
print(categoryNameList);

//Another approach

var categoryNameListWithMap = tags["categories"].map((val) => val["name"]).toList();
print(categoryNameListWithMap);

}
```

Output: [समाचार, अटो, शिक्षा]